# Streaming Video in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I got the ImageAvailableListener working and I tried to process images through the encoder using:

```
private void offerEncoder(byte[] input)
{
    int inputBufferIndex = mEncoder.DequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
    {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mEncoder.GetInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
        inputBuffer.Clear();
        inputBuffer.Put(input);
        mEncoder.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.Length, 0, 0);
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = mEncoder.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
    {
        ByteBuffer outputBuffer = mEncoder.GetOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);
        byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.Size];
        outputBuffer.Get(outData);
        //outputStream.Write(outData, 0, outData.Length);
        mEncoder.ReleaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
        outputBufferIndex = mEncoder.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    }
}
```

But I receiced exception getting the output buffer.

So I decided to use the asynchronous callback.
How are you supposed to handle OnOutputFormatChanged?

I simply call codec.Flush() to clear the buffers and wait for the next image to process. I am not even sure why this is happening since the parameters received are the same as what I set:

```
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);
        //MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat("video/mp4v-es", 640, 480);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, 125000);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, 30);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, (int)MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatyuv420planar);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 5);

        encoder = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType("video/avc");
        //encoder = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType("video/mp4v-es");
        callback = new EncoderCallback();
        encoder.SetCallback(callback);
        encoder.Configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
        encoder.Start();
```

Basically, this is still not working as expected.

Comment: "Any information on this?" is not an on-topic question for SO.  There are numerous existing questions on video streaming with Xamarin here and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: I found out how process frames from the camera.
Now that I have the frame, I need to encode it and send the encoded bytes to a UDP endpoint.

I am sure I can handle the UDP part, but I am trying to find how to get the encoded bytes.

I have no trouble getting an encoder:
encoder = MediaCodec.CreateByCodecName("OMX.google.mpeg4.encoder");

But how to I get the encoded bytes?
Do I set the input surface:
encoder.SetInputSurface(surface);

Then use a listener:
encoder.SetOnFrameRenderedListener(...);

Then get the surface bytes?

Comment: The MediaCodec class has a getInputBuffers method that gives you a ByteBuffer[], and a dequeueInputBuffer method that gives you an index of a buffer in that array that you should fill next. The ByteBuffer class, in turn, has a put(byte[]) method.